# Python Pandas Pivot() with Dates as Column Names Need to Sort and Format

Tags: python, pandas, date, pivot

I've seen the other comments on here about how you can correctly sort the columns when the pivot() makes the date the column name.  What I haven't seen is how to convert those dates to a format I want after the sorting.

Here is my example.  I have data that looks like this:

| category | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 12/1/2018 | 1 | 25 |
| a | 1/1/2019 | 2 | 26 |
| a | 2/1/2019 | 3 | 27 |
| b | 12/1/2018 | 4 | 28 |
| b | 1/1/2019 | 5 | 29 |
| b | 2/1/2019 | 6 | 30 |
| c | 12/1/2018 | 7 | 31 |
| c | 1/1/2019 | 8 | 32 |
| c | 2/1/2019 | 9 | 33 |

What I want is something like this:

| category | value | Dec-18 | Jan-19 | Feb-19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | value1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| a | value2 | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| b | value1 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| b | value2 | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| c | value1 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| c | value2 | 31 | 32 | 33 |

I have figured out how to get pivot to do one value at a time, and to sort the dates as long as I don't try to format them.  But pivot is converting those dates to text so I can't change the format anymore.

This is what I have so far:

**#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%b-%y')
final = df.pivot(index='category', columns='date', values='value1')**

If I do the date formatting first, it sorts incorrectly.  I also tried pivot_table but it won't let me set **aggfunc=None**.

The date formatting has to be dynamic aka every month the date range is going to be different (last 12 months), so I don't want to hard-code the date.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the cleanest solution.

Here's the code I used to reproduce what you have already:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "category":["a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c", "c"],
    "date":["12/1/2018", "1/1/2019", "2/1/2019", "12/1/2018", "1/1/2019", 
    "2/1/2019", "12/1/2018", "1/1/2019", "2/1/2019"], 
    "value1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
    "value2":[25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33],
    })

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.strftime("%b-%y")
```

Then, one can get close to your desired `pandas.DataFrame` with:

```py
df = df.pivot(index="date", columns="category") # rows are `date` and columns are `value-category` pairs
df = df.unstack()                               # Bring back `value1` and `value2` as an index
df = df.reset_index("date")                     # `date` was an index, we bring it back as a column
df = df.pivot(columns="date")                   # Use pandas.DataFrame.pivot() once more to pivot on `date`
df = df.sort_values(by="category")              # Sort output as shown in your desired `pandas.DataFrame`
```

It results in this `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
                     0              
date            Dec-18 Feb-19 Jan-19
       category                     
value1 a             1      3      2
value2 a            25     27     26
value1 b             4      6      5
value2 b            28     30     29
value1 c             7      9      8
value2 c            31     33     32
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I end up with multiple categories which is good, but I can't format the date.  When I try to do this:  pd.to_datetime(df.ACTUAL_DATE).dt.strftime('%b-%y') I get the following error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'.  My date values across the top look like this: 2016-12-01

Comment: So I didn't see the format thing before.  That results in the columns being sorted incorrectly aka Apr-18, Apr-19, Apr-20 instead of Apr-18, May-18, Jun-18.  The only way I've found to correctly sort is to have the date values be in 2016-12-01 before doing the pivot.

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to format the dates.  Any thoughts would be welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check below if it fits into the solution you are looking for

```
    import pandas as pd

 

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "category":["a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c", "c"],
        "date":["12/1/2018", "1/1/2019", "2/1/2019", "12/1/2018", "1/1/2019", 
        "2/1/2019", "12/1/2018", "1/1/2019", "2/1/2019"], 
        "value1": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 
        "value2":[25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33],
        })
    df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) #Convert the date dtype='datetime64[ns]'

    df2= df.pivot(index="date", columns="category")
    df2= df2.unstack() 
    df2= df2.reset_index("date")  
    df2= df2.pivot(columns="date") 
    df2= df2.sort_values(by="category")
    df2 = df2.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
    df2.columns = [x.strftime("%b %Y") for x in df2.columns]
```

The outpuut is shown in the image below.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPhK9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out with a little help from a colleague.

```
df2= df.pivot(index="date", columns="category")
df2= df2.unstack() 
df2= df2.reset_index("date")  
df2= df2.pivot(columns="date") 
df2= df2.sort_values(by="category")
df2.columns = df2.columns.set_levels(summary2.columns.levels[1].strftime('%Y-%b-%d'), level='date')
```

This date format isn't exactly what I was looking for but it works and looks better than the original format.

```
df2= df2.droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
df2.columns = [''.join(col).strip() for col in df2.columns.values]
df2.columns = summary2.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

The table ends up looking like this:

|  | category | 2018-Dec-1 | 2019-Jan-1 | 2019-Feb-1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | a | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| value2 | a | 25 | 26 | 27 |
| value1 | b | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| value2 | b | 28 | 29 | 30 |
| value1 | c | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| value2 | c | 31 | 32 | 33 |